# Can matrix representation be extended to free modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $T$ be an $F$-endomorphism on $V$. Let $\alpha$ be an $F$-basis for $V$. Then, there is a natural $F$-linear isomorphism $[-]_\alpha:End(V)\rightarrow M_n(F)$ where $dim(V)=n$.

Can this concept be extended to modules?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be a free $R$-module with the finite rank $n$. Let $\alpha$ be an $R$-basis for $M$.

Then, I guess that $[-]_\alpha:End_R(V)\rightarrow M_n(R)$ is an $R$-module isomorphism and we can define $\det(\phi)$ for $\phi\in End_R(V)$.

Is there a text introducing linear algebra concpets in the context of module? I'm reading Dummit&Foote, but I hate that he sticks with vector spaces for some concepts even though they can be greatly generalized.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. And you should notice that a matrix with entries in $R$ is invertible iff $\det A$ is an invertible element of $R$. For example, a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $\det A$ is $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @Shalop Yeah I noticed that and proved it before. Do you know any text covering these materials?

Comment: Dummit & Foote. Chapters 11.4 and 11.5 are presented in terms of arbitrary rings. This is all I know. For a more thorough treatment, I have no idea. Maybe Lang?